# Pandas dataframe - different float format for different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatter

I have a list of dicts:

```
list_of_dict = [
    {'Name': 'Shaun' ,  'Rating': 35.0,  'Marks': 9.10  },
    {'Name': 'Suzy'  ,  'Rating': 31.5,  'Marks': 8.7   },
    {'Name': 'Ray'   ,  'Rating': 33  ,  'Marks': 0.0781},
    {'Name': 'Peggy' ,  'Rating': 23  ,  'Marks': 93    },
]
```

And I would like to see it formatted and printed like this:

```
  Rating   Name     Marks
0 35.000  Shaun  9.100000
1 31.500   Suzy  8.700000
2 33.000    Ray  0.078100
3 23.000  Peggy 93.000000
```

When I try

```
import pandas as pd

list_of_dict = [
    {'Name': 'Shaun' ,  'Rating': 35.0,  'Marks': 9.10  },
    {'Name': 'Suzy'  ,  'Rating': 31.5,  'Marks': 8.7   },
    {'Name': 'Ray'   ,  'Rating': 33  ,  'Marks': 0.0781},
    {'Name': 'Peggy' ,  'Rating': 23  ,  'Marks': 93    },
]

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dict,
                  columns=['Rating', 'Name', 'Marks']
                  )

df.style.format(formatter={('Rating'): '{:.3f}',
                           ('Marks') : '{:.6f}'
                          })
print(df)
```

I get this. So it looks like the df.style.format isn't doing anything.

```
   Rating   Name    Marks
0    35.0  Shaun   9.1000
1    31.5   Suzy   8.7000
2    33.0    Ray   0.0781
3    23.0  Peggy  93.0000
```

If I convert to a string like this:

```
df2 = df.to_string(formatters={'Rating':'{:.3f}'.format, 'Marks':'{:.6f}'.format})
print(df2)
```

It gives me the desired result.
So I'v got a working solution, but I still would like to know why the `df.style.format(formatter=..` isn't working..
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your pandas version? For me working both very well.

Comment: pandas 1.3.4

I did a Conda update Yesterday ....

Comment: Are you developing inside a notebook of from a command line?

Comment: I am running this program from Spyder 5.

Comment: If I run directly from the command line (in a Conda environment) the output is the same.
Maybe df.style.format(formatter=  is not meant to be used for printing to a console..?

Comment: I have same issue using PyCharm, python 3.7, pandas 1.3.5: when printing df, no changes show